# Multiple Responses in Excel's Reverse Lookup

Tags: excel, lookup

I'm trying to make a schedule of available workers after they have given me their availability. I would like a list generated of all people who say they can work on a specific day.

[image: Table of data]

Ideally I would create some kind of list that looks like this:

[image: Ideal output table]

I'm actually trying to schedule volunteers for my swim team, not employees, but the idea is the same. The form that they are filling out can also have blank spots (not shown in data table above, but possible) and the dates in the first column will also be out of order. I can manually fix both of those things, but if there is a solution that does not require me to fill in the blanks or sort the dates that would be ideal. I'm using Excel 2019 on a Win10 PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in I2 you would have

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$G$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B$2:$G$7)
/(INDEX($B$2:$G$7,MATCH(I$1,$A$2:$A$7,0),0)="yes"),ROWS($1:1))-COLUMN($A:$A)),"")
```

so you are finding the right row in B2:G7 by doing a match on the date in column A, then finding the first, second, third... column which has a Yes in it, and finally getting the matching name from the first row.

[image]

You can see what's happening by stepping through the formula with evaluate formula:

(1) find the right row in B2:G7 by index/match

[image]

It's matching the date (stored as a number, 43466) against the list of dates in column A. The matching position is 1, which gives the row, and the column parameter in the Index function is 0 so you get the whole row.

(2) Find which cells contain 'yes'

[image]

The values in the array which do contain yes will be replaced with true and the ones which don't will be set to false.

[image]

(3) Do the division

[image]

This is the crux of the whole thing. What aggregate is going to do is to ignore the #div/0 entries (because we used option 6) and work out the lowest (minimum) column which corresponds to a 'yes', which is 2. It's the lowest because rows($1:1) just works out to 1 so you get the 'first smallest'.

(4) Adjust the column so that you get it relative to the first column of B2:G7. You could just subtract 1, but I'm trying to make it so that it still works if you insert a column to the left of the range.

[image]

5) Then all that's left is to index into the list of names in B1:G1

[image]

ending up with Albert.

As the formula is pulled down, rows ($1:1) changes to rows ($1:2) etc. so you get the second smallest column with a yes in it and so you get the second name. Eventually it errors out when there are no more matching names so IFERROR comes into play and you get a blank cell.

Comment: This is a very nice and elegant solution. Thank you very very much. If you have a moment and the interest, could you break down what is happening? I'm trying to learn a bit and I've tried here but I'm still missing something fundamental.

Comment: Thank you! OK will add some steps to my answer.